# Comparing a number to a floating point number?

Tags: php, floating-point

This is my code:

```
$number = 99.99;
$randomNumber = rand(1, 100);

if($randomNumber > $number) {
    // ....
}
```

Could it be that comparing those numbers, the decimal part gets cut off from the 99.99? It seems that its comparing $randomNumber with 99. Could that be and if yes, how can I compare to 99.99?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably, try `$randomNumber = number_format(rand(1, 100), 2);` from **[number_format()](http://us2.php.net/number_format)**

Comment: What makes you think it could be? You've not shown anything to indicate what you expect compared with what you're actually getting to suggest any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`rand`](http://www.php.net/rand) returns an `int`, then PHP will convert `$number` to an `int` to make the comparison.

What you should really do is simply cast it's value to `float`:

```
$number = 99.99;
$randomNumber = (float) rand(1, 100);

if($randomNumber > $number) {
    // ....
}
```

This solves the problem and you don't need any magic trick.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try to do something like this

```
$number = 99.99
$randomNumber = rand(1, 10000);
if ($randomNumber > number * 100)
{
    // ....
}
```

It could do the trick.

Comment: Why does this make sense? O.o

Answer (score 0):

just explode it:

```
$number = 99.99;
$new_num=explode('.',$number)
echo $new_num[0];

//output 99

now you can compare it
```